# HawkNL library, nlClose doesn't close the socket

Tags: delphi, sockets, tcp

Could anyone please help me with the following.

I have a client and server tcp reliable connection.

Client connects to the server, server receives packets. Then Client closes socket (nlclose)
and in the server nlRead still returns 0 (which means that there is still active connection)
It doesn't inform me that client closed the socket, why?

Only nlshutdown on the client side forces the server to stop listening on the socket, Why is that?

Does anyone of you have an experience with hawkNL?

Thanks!

The code run on Windows XP Sp3 box.

EDIT:

The Client code:

```
procedure Client;
const
  TCP_PORT = 9800;
  READ_SIZE_CHUNK = 1048576;//1mb
Type
  TChunk = record
    data: pointer;
    datasize: NLint;
  end;
var
  LRslt: NLboolean;
  LClientSocket: NLsocket;
  LChunkData: TChunk;
  LNumRead: Integer;
  LReadError: NLenum;
  LAddress: NLaddress;
  LWrittenBytes: Integer;
  LBuffer: array [0..10] of byte;

  procedure PopUpMessage(Rslt: NLboolean);
  var
    LError: NLenum;
    LStrRslt: String;
  begin
    if Rslt
      then exit;
    LError := nlGetError();
    if LError = NL_SYSTEM_ERROR
      then LStrRslt := nlGetSystemErrorStr(nlGetSystemError())
      else LStrRslt := nlGetErrorStr(error);
    showmessage (LStrRslt);
    abort;
  end;

begin
  LReadError := 0;
  LRslt := nlInit();PopUpMessage(LRslt);
  LRslt := nlSelectNetwork(NL_IP);PopUpMessage(LRslt);

  LClientSocket := nlOpen(0, NL_TCP);
  if (LClientSocket = NL_INVALID)
    then PopUpMessage(false);

  nlGetLocalAddr(LClientSocket, LAddress);

  //Ustawienie adresu drukarki
  LRslt := nlStringToAddr(PChar('127.0.0.1:'+Inttostr(TCP_PORT)), LAddress); PopUpMessage(Lrslt);
  //Połączenie z drukarką
  LRslt := nlConnect(LClientSocket, LAddress); PopUpMessage(Lrslt);

  LWrittenBytes := nlWrite(LClientSocket, LBuffer, 5);

  if (LWrittenBytes = NL_INVALID)
    then PopUpMessage(false);

  //nlClose(LClientSocket);
end;
```

The Server code:

```
procedure Serwer;
const
  TCP_PORT = 9800;
  READ_SIZE_CHUNK = 1048576;//1mb
Type
  TChunk = record
    data: pointer;
    datasize: NLint;
  end;
var
  LRslt: NLboolean;
  LServerSock, LNewSock: NLsocket;
  LChunkData: TChunk;
  LNumRead: Integer;
  LReadError: NLenum;

  procedure PopUpMessage(Rslt: NLboolean);
  var
    LError: NLenum;
    LStrRslt: String;
  begin
    if Rslt
      then exit;
    LError := nlGetError();
    if LError = NL_SYSTEM_ERROR
      then LStrRslt := nlGetSystemErrorStr(nlGetSystemError())
      else LStrRslt := nlGetErrorStr(error);
    showmessage (LStrRslt);
    abort;
  end;

begin
  LReadError := 0;
  LRslt := nlInit();PopUpMessage(LRslt);
  LRslt := nlSelectNetwork(NL_IP);PopUpMessage(LRslt);

  LServerSock := nlOpen(TCP_PORT, NL_RELIABLE);
  if (LServerSock = NL_INVALID)
    then PopUpMessage(false);

  if not nlListen(LServerSock)
    then PopUpMessage(false);

  repeat
    LNewSock := nlAcceptConnection(LServerSock);
    if LNewSock <> NL_INVALID then
    begin
      GetMem (LChunkData.data, READ_SIZE_CHUNK);
      repeat
        LNumRead := nlRead(LNewSock, LChunkData.data^, READ_SIZE_CHUNK);
        //Here I am receiving 0 bytes reads from LNumRead....
        if LNumRead > 0 then
        begin
          beep;
          //I am receiving stream, do nothing with that
        end else
        begin
          if LNumRead = NL_INVALID then
          begin
            LReadError := nlGetError();
            if (LReadError = NL_INVALID_SOCKET) or
               (LReadError = NL_MESSAGE_END)
              then PopUpMessage(false);
          end;
        end;
      until LReadError <> 0;//(LReadError = NL_NO_PENDING)
      beep;//Here it should exit if all would work ok.
    end else
    begin
      if nlGetError() = NL_SYSTEM_ERROR
        then PopUpMessage(false);
    end;
  until 1=2;
  beep;
end;
```

Comment: Have you seen any evidence of recent development on this project since it seems to have been abandoned since 2004? Why not look at one of the many Delphi network layers that isn't abandoned? (ICS, Indy, RealThinClient SDK, Synapse, and others)

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain of your API? (The [documentation I found](http://hawksoft.com/hawknl/docs/nlRead.html) is remarkably quiet about a `0` return value or orderly closure of the socket.)

The underlying `recv()` or `read()` calls to the TCP stack return `0` when the peer has closed the connection. From the `recv(2)` manpage on my Linux system:

```
RETURN VALUE
   These calls return the number of bytes received, or -1 if an
   error occurred.  The return value will be 0 when the peer has
   performed an orderly shutdown.
```

Note that there might a few bytes or [up to a gigabyte of data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_window_scale_option) or more data left in the socket to read even after a peer has closed a connection. You server application might not get the `FIN` socket-closed notification for a *long* time after the client is done, depending upon the latency and bandwidth of your pipes, your application's IO strategy, and memory available to the TCP/IP stack for buffering socket data.

The *next* `recv()` call (after it has once returned `0`) will return an error. I assume the HawkNL interface to sockets would follow this behavior.

Furthermore, [`nlShutdown`](http://hawksoft.com/hawknl/docs/nlInit.html) appears very different from the usual TCP meaning of `shutdown()`, which simply informs the TCP stack that the application is done reading, writing, or reading and writing, on a single specific socket. Using it in your client might be a little draconian.

**Edit**

I've looked over the HawkNL source a little, and now I'm even more confused about the behavior you're seeing.

```
NL_EXP NLint NL_APIENTRY nlRead(NLsocket socket, NLvoid *buffer, NLint nbytes)
{
    if(driver)
    {
        if(nlIsValidSocket(socket) == NL_TRUE)
        {
            if(buffer == NULL)
            {
                nlSetError(NL_NULL_POINTER);
            }
            else
            {
                NLint received;

                if(nlLockSocket(socket, NL_READ) == NL_FALSE)
                {
                    return NL_INVALID;
                }
                received = driver->Read(socket, buffer, nbytes); /* AAA */

                if(received > 0)
                {
                    nlUpdateSocketInStats(socket, received, 1);
                    nlUpdateInStats(received, 1);
                }
                nlUnlockSocket(socket, NL_READ);
                return received;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            nlSetError(NL_INVALID_SOCKET);
        }
        return NL_INVALID;
    }
    nlSetError(NL_NO_NETWORK);
    return NL_INVALID;
}
```

The point I've marked `/* AAA */` calls into a per-networking-stack `Read` function, and simply returns whatever value comes back from the `Read` function:

```
NLint sock_Read(NLsocket socket, NLvoid *buffer, NLint nbytes)
{
    nl_socket_t *sock = nlSockets[socket];
    NLint       count;

    if(nbytes < 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if(sock->type == NL_RELIABLE || sock->type == NL_RELIABLE_PACKETS) /* TCP */
    {

        /* I've removed all the code for pending non-blocking connections */

        /* check for reliable packets */
        if(sock->type == NL_RELIABLE_PACKETS)
        {
            return sock_ReadPacket(socket, buffer, nbytes, NL_FALSE);
        }
        count = recv((SOCKET)sock->realsocket, (char *)buffer, nbytes, 0); /* BBB */
        if(count == 0)
        {
            /* end of message */
            nlSetError(NL_MESSAGE_END);
            return NL_INVALID;
        }
    }
    /* I removed UDP handling */
```

The portion marked with `/* BBB */` is the call to the system `recv()` function. When the system `recv()` returns `0` (to indicate the peer has closed the socket gracefully), it sets the error state appropriately and returns an error.

Based on your description of the problem, and this source, I'm really surprised. A `0` return looks only possible via the first `if` condition of the `sock_Read()` function: requesting a read of less than `0` bytes **or** via a `NL_RELIABLE_PACKETS` connection when you haven't yet received all of a higher-level *packet* of data. Neither one seems too plausible, so I'm really curious to see your program.

Comment: @sarnold well 0 is returned when there is no more data to read from the buffer, but next nlread calls may return >0 bytes (and it does that way). However when the client closes the socket, nlread doesn't inform that the client socket is invalid or something and the loop reading nlread is still active.

Comment: Wow, that sounds like trouble; I really would expect the _first_ `read()` with a closed socket to return `0`, the _second_ one to return `-1` and set the error to `NL_MESSAGE_END`. Can you post a small reproducer program?

Comment: @sarnold well, for me (at least) it is normal that nlRead can return 0 on reading when the client hasn't sent anything yet. However I expect the "error" status indicating e.g. that the socket has been closed (I will try to prepare small code to reproduce it)

Comment: @sarnold huh, there are lots of lines of the code. If you had some time, there are various delphi examples included in the packet with the interface code and the library itself, available on the site of the HawkNL. It's almost midnight I have to go sleep, and i cannot longer keep my eyes open :( Maybe tomorrow I will try to prepare something.

Comment: @sarnold I think I have the problem with the buffer being sent from client to server. From the code you pasted here I see that the buffer is casted to Char (null terminated string?). I am sending the buffer that way: nlWrite(LSocket, LChunkData.data^, LReadBytes); where data is just: Pointer. SHould I null terminate the data I am sending?

Comment: @John, the `char *` pointer is only being used to point to the beginning of the buffer (the `NLVoid *` from the function parameters). It could store a few hundred `'\0'` bytes, the size is returned into `count` to let you know how much of `buffer` is valid. You shouldn't be `NUL`-terminating your data unless they really are C strings.

Comment: @sarnold I have prepared some code to run. It is in my initial question of this thread. It is not an ideal code (without freeing certain variables) but just for the purpose of the test it is now irrelevant. If you could look at it i would be grateful. Thanks!

Comment: @John, excellent little programs; the only thing that catches my eye is `until LReadError <> 0`. I think terminating on `LNumRead = NL_INVALID` would make more sense. If that isn't it, then I'm completely out of ideas. :(

Comment: @sarnold It behaves strange. Sometimes it works fine, sometimes it hangs on nlread'ings 0 ...I don't know what is going on here. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: @sarnold I have the contact with the author of the library. I have given him the link, so I think we will know what coused the problem :)